# Prototyped custom cell class not displaying objects after push

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

For the solution to this question please see the bottom of this post.

The cells do load the objects on the initial view, the custom cell contains a UIImage view and two UILabels. However, after a cell is selected and a new lot of cells are pushed, the objects on the cell do not appear. They merely appear as blank cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FileCell";
    FileCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[FileCell alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *file = [self.files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *path = [self pathForFile:file];
    BOOL isdir = [self fileIsDirectory:file];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isdir];
    cell.lblFileName.hidden = false;

    if (isdir == true){
        // directory
        cell.lblFileSize.hidden = true;
        CGRect frame = cell.lblFileName.frame;
        frame.origin.y = cell.frame.size.height / 2 - cell.lblFileName.frame.size.height /2;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.imgIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FBFolderIcon"];
    }else{
        // file
        NSFileManager *man = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSDictionary *attrs = [man attributesOfItemAtPath: path error: NULL];
        float result = [attrs fileSize];
        cell.lblFileSize.text = [self stringFromFileSize:result];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        NSString *cellExt = [[file pathExtension] uppercaseString];

        UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FB-%@", cellExt]];

        if (!tempImage) {
            tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FB-%@", @"UNKNOWNTYPE"]];
        }

        cell.imgIcon.image = tempImage;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Update:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.files count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *file = [self.files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *path = [self pathForFile:file];
    if ([self fileIsDirectory:file]) {
        DirectoryBrowserTableViewController *dbtvc = [[DirectoryBrowserTableViewController alloc] init];
        dbtvc.path = path;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dbtvc animated:YES];
    } else {
        if(path == nil){
            return;
        }
        else{
            NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
            if (URL)
            {
                self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];

                self.documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
                [self.documentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectZero                                                           inView:self.tableView animated:YES];
            }}
    }
}
```

**Screenshots:**

[Initial view, when file browser tab is loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HylG.png)

[After selecting the folder cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpGtK.png)

**Solution:**

Okay, so the problem seems to have been the fact that I was allocating a new instance of the current table view and pushing it upon one of the cells being pressed. To fix the problem of the labels not appearing in my second view, I changed from protoype cells to a UITableCell in the form of a NIB file.

Just remember to add this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FileManagerCell" bundle:nil]
         forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FileManagerCell"];
}
```

And in the table view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//The name of the cell that we registered in the viewDidLoad method.
    static  NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FileManagerCell";

//FileCell is the name of the class that I have associated with the NIB file.
    FileCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[FileCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

return cell;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: show remaining code of uitableview

Comment: what do you mean **The cells do load the objects on the initial view?**...

Comment: Please see edited post, I have added screenshots and the remaining code.

Comment: Glad you found out what was causing your troubles.

Comment: Hi Terry, next time - feel free to just answer your own question - please don't post solutions in the question itself (it breaks our Q&A model)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hard to answer without seeing more code. How does DirectoryBrowserTableViewController look like for example? I guess that ViewController is the one being displayed when you select a folder?

Without knowing more about the context I can only guess but I would start looking at your implementation of numberOfRowsInSection (in DirectoryBrowserTableViewController). Does it return the currect number of files in your directory? If it returns zero I guess you would end up with an empty tableview.

Comment: There are two screenshots hyperlinked in the original question, unfortunately I couldn't attach the images in the "standard" post format due to my reputation being below the threshold.

The cells are present, as far as I am aware anyway. I am able to tap a cell and bring up it's respective activity menu, so far it just seems as if it is an issue relating to the appearance.

Comment: Is the code you are showing from DirectoryBrowserTableViewController or from some other class?

Comment: Yes it is from DirectoryBrowserTableViewController, all the provided code is from that class.

Comment: Just so that I understand what is going on, how is "self.files" being updated?

Comment: self.files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:self.path error:nil];

This is called on the - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{} method.

I don't think the objects are being added to the new cells when the view is pushed, when I try to log the text property of the UILabels they return empty, also, self.files, is working fine, I'm sure. I just logged the index of the array and it returned the correct values.